# Binding inputField to Bean in XPages

Tags: java, binding, xpages, serverside-javascript

I am trying to bind an inputField to a bean, but i get the the following error in webbrowser

```
Error getting property 'Name' from bean of type com.app.PersonModel
```

faces-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>person</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.app.PersonModel</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
 </faces-config>
```

XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:inputText id="Name" value="#{person.Name}"></xp:inputText>

</xp:view>
```

Java Bean

```
package com.app;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PersonModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String Name;
    public PersonModel(){
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from person.Name to person.name. So do this instead when referencing the name property on your XPage:

```
<xp:inputText id="Name" value="#{person.name}"></xp:inputText>
```

Comment: probably your don't want to start field names Uppercase